# Implementing random oracle (output is random in the range but output is same for the same input) in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I wish to implement a [random oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) in C++. Essentially, just a function f: {1,...,n} -> [0,1], so that for each input i in {1, ..., n}, the output f(i) is a random value in [0,1]. But *importantly*, every invocation of f(i) should return the same value.

In other words, I want a very large table f of independently and identically distributed random variables in [0,1] indexed by integers. Of course, I don't want to precompute the table and store it. Instead, I want that this table be implemented on the fly. You give input i, and you get value from table f(i).

What is the best way to implement it? One possibility is to use the input integer i itself as seed to random number generator. Then f(i)  would be random number generated with i as seed. Is this good enough? Thanks!

(This question has been edited based on helpful comments.)

Comment: So you had a problem, successfully solved it on your own and you're just asking if there's a better way?

Comment: I am certainly asking for a better way. Also, I think the main issue which I should have mentioned in the post is the following: RandomHash(x) = RandomHash(y) would imply same values for RandomFunction(x) and RandomFunction(y). How likely is this? Is there something robust?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why not simply use x directly as a seed? What's the advantage of hashing it first?

Comment: @KillianDS The reason is that by itself x will be a poor seed for random number generation. So the output will not be random in [0,1].

Comment: @MadhavJha no matter how poor your seed is, that randomness should be entirely determined by the generator itself.

Comment: @BЈовић Maybe I should just remove the code that I wrote. It appears to be distracting from the main question. Here's what I want. I want a very large table f of independently and identically distributed random variables in [0,1] indexed by integers (in the range of 100 million). Of course, I don't want to precompute the table and store it. Instead, I want that this table be implemented on the fly. You give input i, and you get value from table f(i). I searched stackoverflow, but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @KillianDS Yeaah, it now seems that an extra-level of hashing is probably unnecessary. I have also modified my question to directly ask what I want.

Comment: @MadhavJha Does it have to be cutting-edge fast? A cryptographic hash function will do exactly what you want, by design, is extremely high quality (again, by design), and is rather fast especially for fixed-size integers (it also takes no memory, you don't need to store an immense table). Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: @Thomas You are right. I was hoping to find something lightweight. Do you have any suggested C++ libraries in mind? Could this be implemented in C++ directly without having to import a library using the latest C++ 11 <random>'s features perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: @MadhavJha: A hash function is a pretty good way to go. If you implement sha512 for instance, there are 2^512 unique numbers in your table. That's a (very) big number, so whilst there is a probability of collision, its really really small.

Comment: Bouncy castle http://www.bouncycastle.org/ is a good crypto library

Comment: @Thomas actually, if the output should be a floating point number between 0 and 1 you still need the conversion from the hash output to that, which might be tricky if you want a uniform distribution.

Comment: @KillianDS Take the lower 64 (or 128, if you happen to have a quad precision FP type) bits and divide by 2^64 or 2^128 respectively. No distribution problem here (for once, floating point numbers don't get in the way)

Comment: @Thomas And why would that be uniform between 0 and 1? Usually floating point numbers have (much) more values around 0, so you'd tend up with a very biased distribution with much values towards zero and few values towards 1.

Comment: @KillianDS That would apply to any scheme using floating-pointn umbers, not specifically a hash function... If that is a real problem then using an accurate real manipulation library is probably in order.

Comment: @Thomas [why?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

Comment: The question has been put on hold as being off topic which I fail to understand. It is a "a specific programming problem". In my previous edits, I included my own attempt and asked for specific question. I think I definitely meet bullet 3 of http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and definitely followed most (if not all) the checklist here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than constructing a new random engine and distribution each time you call the function, you may use the following approach:

```
class F
{
    private:
       std::mt19937 generator;
       std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution; // choose your distribution here.
    public:
       F() : generator(), distribution(0, 1) {} // lower and upper bound here
       auto operator()(const size_t n) -> decltype(distribution(generator))
       {
          generator.seed(n);
          return distribution(generator);
       }
};
```

Usage is trivial:

```
 int main()
 {
    F f;
    for ( size_t i(0); i < 10; ++i )
    {
       std::cout << f(i) << "\n";
    } 
 }
```

It seeds the generator with the a well-defined number, namely yours and then returns a value in that distribution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use the seed itself as the oracle input?  That would (probably) make the time to use constant, instead of linear.

Comment: @PatrickM Correct, that would make it constant time. I had a doubt about it destroying uniformity (or whatever you choose), but apparently it doesn't (I just checked). I'll modify my answer shortly.

Comment: Generally they try to make even a change of even 1 in the seed totally re-randomize everything.  It's not a given, but it's usually close enough unless you have a determined attacker trying to reverse-engineer what you're doing.

Comment: This looks good. I had something similar in mind. I think I just need to use it in my application to see if it works. I still have my fears about "collisions" as mentioned in comments to the question.

Comment: @MadhavJha Well if you're asking for randomness, you can't avoid collisions. The likelyhood depends on the number of values in your range and the number of items you want. If you want to assert that there will be no collisions, you'd have to use a different approach.